# "AttributeError: no attribute 'download " With PyTube

Tags: python, pytube

## I have a problem with pytube when  use YouTube

```
from pytube import YouTube
url = str(input("Youtube video url :"))
youtube = YouTube(url)
stream = youtube.streams()
video.download(0)
```

### this error shows

```
AttributeError: 'YouTube' object has no attribute 'download'
```

### and when I use playlist

```
from pytube import Playlist
playlist = Playlist('https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLRfY4Rc-GWzhdCvSPR7aTV0PJjjiSAGMs')
print('Number of videos in playlist: %s' % len(playlist.video_urls))
playlist.download_all()
```

### Shows the same error

```
AttributeError: 'Playlist' object has no attribute 'download_all'
```

Comment: Follow the [documentation](https://python-pytube.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the first stream from the `Stream` of the `YouTube` object that you created. If you look at [the documentation](https://python-pytube.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) you could have know this.

Try this for downloading the video:

```py
from pytube import YouTube
url = str(input("Youtube video url :"))
youtube = YouTube(url)
youtube.streams.first().download()
```

For the playlist try this:

```py
from pytube import Playlist
playlist = Playlist('https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLRfY4Rc-GWzhdCvSPR7aTV0PJjjiSAGMs')
print('Number of videos in playlist: %s' % len(playlist.video_urls))

# Loop through all videos in the playlist and download them
for video in playlist.videos:
    video.streams.first().download()
```

Answer (score 1):

Youtube function doesn't have function "download" i.e using Youtube we cannot download a video.

Eg:
yt = YouTube(url).download()
#output = error

Only using streams we can download a video. It is not needed to import stream.

Eg:
yt = YouTube(url).streams.download()
#output = success