# List YouTube playlist URLs using pytube python

Tags: python, youtube, pytube

I have searched for the topic and I am trying to find a way to list the URLs or links of specific playist.
Here's what I got but didn't work for me

```
import re
from pytube import Playlist

playlist = Playlist("https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGCkg2uj3PxUWhMDuTw3VKjM")
playlist._video_regex = re.compile(r"\"url\":\"(/watch\?v=[\w-]*)")
print('Number of videos in playlist: %s' % len(playlist.video_urls))
for url in playlist.video_urls:
   print(url)
```

I got the number of videos 0.
Any idea how to make this code work?

And this is another code that is supposed to download all the links from the playlist

```
from pytube import Playlist
 
try:
    playlist = Playlist('https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLcow8_btriE11hzMbT3-B1sBg4YIc-9g_') 
    playlist.download_all(download_path='./Videos')
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

But I got this `'Playlist' object has no attribute 'download_all'`

Comment: your code does work fine for me. Problem is likely with the output.

Comment: I tried the above script and it works as expected, I get the output: `Number of videos in playlist: 23` with the url dumps in the loop.

Comment: so what may cause the code not to work for me? I am using Jupyter Notebook. Is that may be the reason?

Comment: No, notebooks have nothing to do with that. Try upgrading pytube to newer version

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have used `pip uninstall pytube` then install it `python -m pip install pytube` and now it works well

Comment: I have updated the question and added another sub-question. I am trying to download all the links of the playlist but that is not working although I have updated the package of pytube.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64906882/attributeerror-no-attribute-download-with-pytube Get the stream first.

Comment: @CiaranOBrien Thanks a lot. I think the code I posted as an answer is exactly the same as in your link. Thank you very much.

Comment: @YasserKhalil You were missing the 'stream' section in your code. The link I shared has this. I see below you added and answer where you copied this code. Glad that it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works well for me

```
from pytube import Playlist

playlist = Playlist('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EWdNhA5prXQ&list=PLRhWUdOnZHklr5GcNBO7dDsTspk85M8eH')
print('Number Of Videos In playlist: %s' % len(playlist.video_urls))

for video in playlist.videos:
    video.streams.first().download()
```